# jQuery fade effect on replacing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling to find a solution for a `fade` effect with this script. I'm still learning basic jQuery, but cant seem to figure it out. The script is working fine, the divs are replacing, but with no animation. I have tried fadeToggle, fadeIn and fadeOut.

```
function HideContent(d) {
    if(d.length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}

function ShowContent(d) {
    if(d.length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    $('#' + d).fadeToggle('slow');
}
```

I call the script with onmouseclick. I have about 14 different divs.

```
<a  onmouseclick="ShowContent('div1'); return true; "href="javascript:ShowContent('div1')"> Link button </a>
```

and to go back:

```
<a onmouseclick="HideContent('div1'); return true;" href="javascript:HideContent('div1')"> BACK </a>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You should also use `onclick` instead of `onmouseclick`. An even better solution would be to bind the click events (http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the `div` in your initialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues in your code, but the one stopping the animation happens because you already changed the display CSS style to `block` before you call the fadeToggle. Try the code below instead.

```
function HideContent(d) {
    if(d.length < 1) {
        return; 
    }

    // document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    // replace the above line with:
    // $('#' + d).css('display','none');

    // or even better, fade it out:
    $('#' + d).fadeOut('slow');
}

function ShowContent(d) {
    if(d.length < 1) {
        return; 
    }
    // document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    // You don't need the above, the fadeToggle does this for you.

    $('#' + d).fadeIn('slow');
}
```